# Unit test using junit 4.10

Tags: unit-testing, junit4

Using JUnit 4.10 here is my test.

```
package geometry;

import org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SegmentTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {

    @Test
    public void SegmentParallelTest() {
        Segment a = new Segment(10, 5, 20, 11);
        Segment b = new Segment(20, 6, 30, 11);
        assertFalse(a.isParallel(b));
    }

    public static junit.framework.Test suite() {
        return new junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter(SegmentTest.class);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("geometry.SegmentTest");
    }
}
```

Which produces the following error message...

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in geometry.SegmentTest
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are extending `TestCase` which expects test methods to start with `test` in their name. Remove the `extends junit.framework.TestCase` and it will work fine.

```
package geometry;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

public class SegmentTest {

    @Test
    public void segmentParallelTest() {
        Segment a = new Segment(10, 5, 20, 11);
        Segment b = new Segment(20, 6, 30, 11);
        assertFalse(a.isParallel(b));
    }

}
```

Comment: If I remove the extends - cannot file symbol methods assertFalse(boolean).

Comment: You will need to static import `assertFalse(boolean)`. See above code in my answer.